# Show that $-a=a\forall a\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring for which there is a positive even integer $n$ such that $a^n=a$. Show that $-a=a\forall a\in R$.

**Attempt**:

Let $n=2m$.
Consider $2a\in R$ then $(2a)^{2m}=2a\implies4^m a^{2m}=2a\implies 4^m a=2a\implies a(4^m-2)=0$

How to show that $2a=0\forall a$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $n$ is even, $a^{n}=(-a)^n$.

Comment: It took me a second, then BAM.